# Understand the plumbing behind running RasberryPI code from Freenove in Python

Tags: python-3, c

I have downloaded some pre-made code from Freenove - https://github.com/Freenove/Freenove_Ultimate_Starter_Kit_for_Raspberry_Pi

Freenove uses WiringPi. So I downloaded `WiringPi` and ran `build`.

Question 1  - Does `build` compiles the `.c` code in `WiringPi`, specifically the `wiringPi` library? Where is the library kept on the system?

Then I build the `Blink.c` code at `https://github.com/Freenove/Freenove_Ultimate_Starter_Kit_for_Raspberry_Pi/blob/master/Code/C_Code/01.1.1_Blink/Blink.c` and executed the code using `-lwiringPi` option. The program ran fine.

The I executed the `python` version of the code `https://github.com/Freenove/Freenove_Ultimate_Starter_Kit_for_Raspberry_Pi/tree/master/Code/Python_Code/01.1.1_Blink` using `python3`. That worked fine as well.

While I understand how the `C` code is working by following the `wiringPi` reference guide here `http://wiringpi.com/reference/setup/`, I don't understand the function calls and modules from the `Python` code.

Eg. where is `import RPi.GPIO as GPIO` defined and where should I look to find the functions available within `RPi.GPIO` and their meanings?

https://github.com/Freenove/Freenove_Ultimate_Starter_Kit_for_Raspberry_Pi/blob/master/Code/Python_Code/01.1.1_Blink/Blink.py

Where is `from gpiozero import LED` defined in `Blink2.py` - https://github.com/Freenove/Freenove_Ultimate_Starter_Kit_for_Raspberry_Pi/blob/master/Code/Python_Code/01.1.1_Blink/Blink2.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WiringPi is a C library used to access the GPIO. It is pre-installed in Raspbian.

RPi.GPIO is a Python module to access the GPIO. It is pre-installed in Raspbian.

gpiozero is a Python module to access the GPIO. It is pre-installed in Raspbian.

Comment: Thanks. In addition, I was looking for this - https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Examples/ and https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/